# Multiple Split and Map in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, rdd

I have the below after a split with `#` of a file,

```
res64: Array[(String, String)] = Array((1,Animation|Children's|Comedy), (2,Adventure|Children's|Fantasy))
```

How to get unique pair (using distinct) like `(1, Animation),(1,Children's)`, etc.. for every `key`(movie id here) like 1 in the `RDD`?

Answer (score 0):

can be as simple as

```
rdd.mapValues(x => x.split('|'))\
.flatMapValues(x=>x)\ 
.distinct()\
.collect()
```